# Почему строка обрезается после шифрования RSA?

Tags: java, криптография, rsa

Я шифрую строку `g*n&!x0$:!=<dU(kQWERTY` с помощью rsa и этого java кода

```
        byte[] b1 = str.getBytes();
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(
                "16525648303494844625323402605846669619741304501558279708339326184628819475922357171950792902598962638332933642213408591387110085680143659053757446696930098854122596628234296086934734034290995916016651168042154443556317752125709466628134047856991708808057246062192841541521946966512021233224533083590339910211588425975324845977323920826617383934171594783689409473889580963244583313901462695715714347667479099308052988869350189996108003615357436616996135397866045472128523104209819453141321086305323341618875443118814585750925120734519476575597841843964742187720702473316398232523091421108414392602556707958158245097651");
        BigInteger pubExp = new BigInteger("65537");
        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, pubExp);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey publicKey2 = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey2);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(b1);
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText));
```

однако при расшифровке я получаю строку `g*n&!x0$:!=`. Почему это происходит?

Comment: Попробовал без < и расшифровалось без проблем.

Comment: Можно спросить с какой целью вы это делаете? Если для подписи, то вроде есть уже готовые классы.